# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Insert of object

Tags: sql, jpa, persistence

SRAssignment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SR_ASSIGNEMENT", uniqueConstraints= { @UniqueConstraint
(columnNames="SRAID")})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SRASSIGNMENT_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
public class SRAssignment implements Serializable{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
generator="SRASSIGNMENT_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name="SRAID", nullable=false)
private long sraId;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPNO")
private Employee employee;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="srNo", optional=false)
private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="assignedBy")
private Employee assignedBy;

@Column(name="ASSIGNEDON")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
private Date assignedOn;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true, mappedBy="slotNo")
private ScheduleSlot startSlot;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , optional=true, mappedBy="slotNo")
private ScheduleSlot expectedEndSlot;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , optional=true, mappedBy="slotNo")
private ScheduleSlot actualEndSlot;

@Column(name="SRA_COMMENT", nullable=true)
private String comment;

@Column(name="ATTACHMENT", nullable=true)
private Object attachment;

....
```

ServiceRequest.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SERVICE_REQUEST", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames=     
{"SRNO"})})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SERVICE_REQUEST_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class ServiceRequest implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
generator="SERVICE_REQUEST_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name="SRNO",  nullable=false)
private long srNo;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name="STATUS") 
private int status;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CUSTNO", referencedColumnName="CustNO")
private Customer customer;

@Column(name="DATECREATED")
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name="DATEUPDATED")
private Date dateUpdated;
...


ServiceRequest request = workPersistence.getRequestById(assigner.getRequestId());
Employee employee = workPersistence.getEmployeeById(assigner.getTechnician());
Employee manager = workPersistence.getEmployeeById(assigner.getAssignedBy());
SRAssignment assignment = new SRAssignment();

assignment.setEmployee(employee);
assignment.setAssignedBy(manager);
assignment.setServiceRequest(request);
assignment.setAssignedOn(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(assignment);
em.refresh(assignment);
System.out.println("refresh assignment, now commiting...");
tx.commit();
```

Error I get is:

refresh assignment, now commiting...
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction failed to commit
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:118)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.persistence.JpaWorkPersistence.assignRequest(JpaWorkPersistence.java:417)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.impl.WorkServiceImpl.getRequestAssigned(WorkServiceImpl.java:146)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.impl.WorkServiceImpl.assignRequest(WorkServiceImpl.java:112)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.test.WorkServiceTest.testServiceRequestAssignment(WorkServiceTest.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Insert of object "com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.SRAssignment@7edab86b" using statement **"INSERT INTO SR_ASSIGNEMENT (ASSIGNEDBY,SRA_COMMENT,EMPNO,ASSIGNEDON,SRAID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" failed
: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DSP_QA_4"."SR_ASSIGNEMENT"."SRNO")**

```
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:270)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:116)
    ... 25 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DSP_QA_4"."SR_ASSIGNEMENT"."SRNO")

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.executeStatementUpdate(SQLController.java:419)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.InsertRequest.execute(InsertRequest.java:411)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertTable(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:166)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:142)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2377)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3769)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3884)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3807)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3747)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4137)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:400)
    at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:288)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityTransaction.commit(JPAEntityTransaction.java:103)
    ... 25 more
```

**Why it doesnt get serviceRequest information and doesnot get SRNO to insert in the assignment?
Also On the same relation when I attempt following :**

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Query query = em
.createQuery(
"SELECT assignment FROM SRAssignment assignment WHERE assignment.sraId = :sraId")
            .setParameter("sraId", new Long(assignmentId));
List<SRAssignment> assignments = query.getResultList();
SRAssignment sra = (SRAssignment) assignments.get(0);
    System.out.println(sra.getSraId());
    System.out.println(sra.getEmployee().getEmpNo());
    System.out.println("________________________________________");
    System.out.println(sra.getServiceRequest().getSrNo());
    System.out.println();
    em.close();
```

As soon as I hit the line 
        **System.out.println(sra.getServiceRequest().getSrNo());**

I get error as:
    ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-88" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testGetAssignmentById' defined in URL [bundle://178.33:0/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Inv
ocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot perform operation "==" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ObjectExpression@843249a and org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.express
ion.NumericExpression@7017feb2
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot perform operation "==" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ObjectExpression@843249a and org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.NumericExpression@7017feb2
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAAdapter.getApiExceptionForNucleusException(JPAAdapter.java:898)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.isLoaded(JDOStateManager.java:1736)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.SRAssignment.jdoGetserviceRequest(SRAssignment.java)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.SRAssignment.getServiceRequest(SRAssignment.java:151)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.persistence.JpaWorkPersistence.getAssignmentsByAssignmentId(JpaWorkPersistence.java:462)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.test.WorkServiceTest.testGetAssignmentById(WorkServiceTest.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.IllegalExpressionOperationException: Cannot perform operation "==" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ObjectExpression@843249a and org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.express
ion.NumericExpression@7017feb2
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.SQLExpression.eq(SQLExpression.java:383)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.ObjectExpression.eq(ObjectExpression.java:217)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatement.getJoinConditionForJoin(SQLStatement.java:1232)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatement.join(SQLStatement.java:1151)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatement.leftOuterJoin(SQLStatement.java:892)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatement.leftOuterJoin(SQLStatement.java:848)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatementHelper.addJoinForOneToOneRelation(SQLStatementHelper.java:995)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.SQLStatementHelper.selectMemberOfSourceInStatement(SQLStatementHelper.java:839)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.processMembersOfClass(FetchRequest.java:488)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.FetchRequest.(FetchRequest.java:166)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.getFetchRequest(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:339)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.fetchObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:316)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1634)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadSpecifiedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1236)
        at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.isLoaded(JDOStateManager.java:1724)
        ... 25 more

Comment: who knows? you have the log, and it includes such things. Perhaps not specifying the sequenceName doesn't help?

Comment: I gave a try with not specifying sequenceName but the same result...

Comment: What do you mean you gave it a try? You aren't specifying the sequenceName above and really ought to. As I said the log tells you all

Comment: I get the same error with/without sequenceName specified. generator name and seq name are same. I m not sure what exactly you are refering in log file. ........                                      I m setting SRAssignment's serviceRequest object (that exists in db), but when persisting SRAssignment it is not attmpting to insert serviceRequest. ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it now...
The JPA spec does not allow a uni-direction OneToOne with the foreign key in the target table. It requires to define a OneToOne in both directions ..
so i have defined onetoone in serviceRequest to use a myppedBy...
I modified SRAssignment as:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinColumn(name="SRNO", nullable=false)
private ServiceRequest serviceRequest;
```

and ServiceRequest as:

```
@OneToOne (fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true,  mappedBy="serviceRequest")
private SRAssignment assignment;
```

Thanks